# Calculating Distance From a Line To Point

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Hello everyone I have a point $P$ and a line $l$.

And I need to find all the $X$ points that for them

the distance from $X$ to $P$ is the half distance from $X$ to $l$ in $2d$.

I tried to use the distance formula but I didn't success.

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about $\mathbb{R}^n$ and not some abstract normed vector space?

Comment: No I am talking about 2d

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^2$ draw the perpendicular from $P$ to $l$.  Now perpendicularly bisect this line call the bisector $m$, also reflect this line about $l$, call it $n$. The lines $m$ and $n $ form such a locus.

Comment: How can I proof that is symmetric around the origin?

Comment: You can’t prove it’s symmetric about the origin in general it’s not. For that, the line through $P$ and the origin must be perpendicular to $l$ and $P$ must lie between $l$ and the origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can very well use the distance formula. If we have $P(a,b)$ and $L: lx+my+n=0$, then any point $X(x,y)$ must satisfy $$\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2} = \frac 12 \cdot \frac{|lx+my+n|}{\sqrt{l^2+m^2}} $$ Now just square and simplify. You should get the locus of $X$ as $$x^2(3l^2+4m^2) +y^2(4l^2+3m^2) -x(8al^2+8am^2+2ln) -y(8bl^2+8bm^2+2mn) +xy(2lm) +4(l^2+m^2)(a^2+b^2) -n^2=0$$

Comment: I’m not sure that I’d call that a simplification.

Comment: @amd What would you call it then?